# ActiveAdmin: X has_and_belongs_to_many Y, want to create a new Y from the form for X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have a Gallery model and an Images model, where a Gallery has_and_belongs_to_many Images.

Right now, new images are uploaded via the images form, and a gallery's images are selected from the gallery form using checkboxes. I'd like to keep the existing checkbox selection method for existing images, but also be able to upload new images from within the gallery form (and simultaneously create the association between the new image and the gallery).

Here is my gallery form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @gallery] do |g| %>
  <%= g.inputs "Details" do %>
    <%= g.input :title %>
    <%= g.input :images, :as => :check_boxes, :label_method => Proc.new { |image| image_tag(image.thumb_path, :alt => "") + content_tag("h3", image.title)  } %>
  <% end %>
  <%= g.inputs "Images" do %>
    <% g.has_many :images do |i| %>
      <%= i.input :title %>
      <%= i.input :asset, :as => :file %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= g.buttons %>
<% end %>
```

I am seeing the following error when I browse to the form:

```
undefined method `has_many' for #<Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder:0xb410d4c>
```

I'm still learning Rails and I'm totally new to ActiveAdmin, so I may be missing something obvious here. I'm happy to provide more context if that would be helpful.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have accepts_nested_attributes set up ...

First create a blank image
`@gallery.images.build`
then build input fields for the new image

```
<% g.inputs :for => :images do |image| %>
  <% if image.new_record? %>
        <%= image.input :title %>
        <%= image.input :asset, :as => :file %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry to remove my answer acceptance, but this only seems to add a file upload for each of the already extant gallery images... see [http://i.imgur.com/3DX36.jpg](http://i.imgur.com/3DX36.jpg)

Comment: so that's a slightly different problem. If you want to add a file upload for a new image, you should build a blank image object before creating the form `@gallery.images.build`.  If you want to add multiple images, you need some jquery and an 'add one more' button ...